# How to use "be + going to" and the present continuous?

Tags: grammar

I wonder how to use "be + going to" and the present continuous.

For examples:

If I say

> I’m leaving tomorrow.

does that mean I’ve got my plane/train ticket? And if I say the sentence

> I’m going to leave tomorrow.

do I need to have a ticket with me or not?

Another example:

> She’s going to the exhibition tomorrow.

is exactly like “She’s going to go to the exhibition tomorrow” or not?

Comment: To learn the use of be+going to with present progressive tense ( present continuous tense), please view this link as reference. It contains lots of examples that will help you to understand the usage. http://www.englishgrammar.org/present-progressive/

Answer (score 3):

For your first question - either sentence is fine, regardless of whether you have your ticket. If you want to say something about tickets, you need to say so explicitly.

For your second question - yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's really more of a language structure thing, less about meaning - unless you want precision.

> I leave tomorrow.  [ simple or poetic ]
>
> I am leaving tomorrow.  [ ordinary, common use ]
>
> I am going to leave tomorrow.  [ a bit more emphatic, still common ]
>
> I will be leaving tomorrow.  [ Future tense, also a bit more emphatic ]

All say that I leave tomorrow.