# Be going to or verb-ing in this context?

Tags: exam-questions, future-time

Here's a not very clear exam question, in my opinion at least, it asks to circle the correct answer in:

> It seems that our neighbors are (having/going to have) a party this weekend. This is our invitation.

What do you think?

Comment: Both answers are equally good, unless there was more context to the question, such as requiring a particular part of speech.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is better way to say about a future plans?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/144628/what-is-better-way-to-say-about-a-future-plans) See also [Are we having classes tomorrow? vs Do we have classes tomorrow?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122519/) and [How to use “be + going to” and the present continuous?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10177/)